# OData v4 custom route using DTO problems

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, odata

I have setup an OData v4 controller from an EF 6 model.  All works fine when using the generated code.

On some objects that will be referenced in drop downs I want to limit the data sent so DTOs seem like the best approach.  So I now have a controller the works fine with the normal object but as soon as I use a DTO on a custom route I run into trouble.

I've used the code below and it generated the DTO collection properly but when it returns the data I end up on the client with a 406 Not Acceptable status.

Any suggestions about what is going wrong?

As a side note, is my strategy of wanting to provide a full and a cut down object the best way to do it (so far as standards go)?

```
    // GET: odata/AMO_GeneralStateTypes(5)/AMO_GeneralStates_Basic
    [EnableQuery]
    [Route("odata/AMO_GeneralStateTypes({key})/AMO_GeneralStates_Basic")]
    public IQueryable<AMO_GeneralStatesDTO> GetAMO_GeneralStates_Basic([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return db.AMO_GeneralStateTypes
            .Where(m => m.StateTypeId == key)
            .SelectMany(m => m.AMO_GeneralStates.Select(n => new AMO_GeneralStatesDTO()
            {
                StateId = n.StateId,
                StateGuid = n.StateGuid,
                ParentStateId = n.ParentStateId,
                State = n.State,
                TypeId = n.TypeId,
                SortOrder = n.SortOrder,
                Enabled = n.Enabled
            }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For 406 Not Acceptable, please make sure the return type is defined in the finally Edm Model. That is, AMO_GeneralStatesDTO is type that Edm model can serialize.

BTW, For Web API OData,

> [Route("odata/AMO_GeneralStateTypes({key})/AMO_GeneralStates_Basic")]

should be

> [ODataRoute("odata/AMO_GeneralStateTypes({key})/AMO_GeneralStates_Basic")]

Comment: Thanks Sam.  That helped me clear up one issue - I had thought that the scaffold was using Odata v4 but it is in fact V3, The scaffold for V4 seems to be in a very early state so I think that I'll just use Odata 3 for now.

Comment: Whoops - I meant to add the question, adding this builder.EntitySet<AMO_GeneralStatesDTO>("AMO_GeneralStatesDTO"); to the model doesn't seem to help.  Would that be the way to do it or have I misunderstood.  Thanks @sam-xu

Answer (score 0):

I have met some problems like this in odata webapi for dto
here is my solution: you need to register your entitytype for odata or it will come a 406 error

```
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntityType<YourDTOType>();
```

Hope it's helpful